# Saving float changes to a float or to a varchar2 column?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to save before and after value changes of certain fields of an `items` table to an `items_log` table. Changes are saved by an after change trigger on the `items` table.

Some of the `items` table columns are `varchar2` type and some are `number(*)` type.

What is the better approach? Saving to separate two before and after `number` fields and two before and after `varchar2` fields? Or conserving space by saving everything to two before and after `varchar2` fields?

The purpose of this log table is to record which user changed a field and the before and after values.

**Could saving a float value to a string field lead to an unexpected diversion from the original value?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your purpose in recording the changes? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: The most pragmatic approach is to maintain a separate table which logs the whole  old (pre-change) record. Logging before and after values for individual columns seems attractive, but it becomes a problem when we want to reconstruct the prior state of a changed record.

Answer (score 0):

"What is the better approach?"

There is no "better" approach. There is only an approach that's good enough for your application. If your table will have a few thousand rows in it, it doesn't really matter. If your table will have a few million rows, then space may be more of a concern.

If your goal is to display to a user what changes occurred to your item and it's not going to see a lot of activity, storing everything as a varchar may be good enough. You probably don't want to store rows for fields that did not change.

I use APC's approach often. The `items_log` table is the same as the item table, and includes a history id, timestamp, action (I, U, or D), and user along with all the columns of the item row. Everything is maintained by a trigger. There are also built-in Oracle auditing features to do auditing for you.